# I dont know whats reall anymore typeError: cannot read property 'cartItems' of undefined at Object.$scope.calGrandTotal

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, dao, intellij-14

I dont know what's real anymore.

I've been having this problem for about 1 month it's based on a tutorial at udemy tutorial here [building an eccomerce store java spring mvc](https://www.udemy.com/building-an-e-commerce-store-using-java-spring-framework/)

The tutorial itself came with 0 files you pretty much have to copy him and pray it works

For some reason the cartitems is persisting to the database however they are not bieng place on the cart view after the post. I'm using AngularJS for the two way databinding

I can see that the data is persisting so im lead to believe that the error is with the angular but can't quite be sure

My reason for believing this is that the error would been more adjusted to the models upon parsing through the angular and more into the program. I'm talking more like a scifi buff than a programmer but this is the best way to describe something like this.

thanks guys any help would be appreciated

Here's the controller for angular:

```
/**
 * Created by dwight on 4/8/2016.
 */

var cartApp = angular.module ('cartApp', []);

cartApp.controller('cartCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.refreshCart = function () {
        $http.get('/emusicstore/rest/cart/' + $scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.cart = data;

        });

    };

    $scope.clearCart = function() {
        $http.delete('/emusicstore/rest/cart/' + $scope.cartId).success($scope.refreshCart());
    };

    $scope.initCartId = function(cartId){
        $scope.cartId = cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart(cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function(productId){
        $http.put('/emusicstore/rest/cart/add/'+productId).success(function(){
            alert('Product successfully added to the cart!')
        });
    };

    $scope.removeFromCart = function(productId){
        $http.put('/emusicstore/rest/cart/remove/'+productId).success(function(data){
            $scope.refreshCart();


        });
    };

    $scope.calGrandTotal = function(){
        var grandTotal=0;

        for(var i=0; i<$scope.cart.cartItems.length; i++){
            grandTotal+=$scope.cart.cartItems[i].totalPrice;
        }

        return grandTotal;
    };


});

heres the model

    package com.emusicstore.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by dwight on 4/4/2016.
 */
@Entity
public class CartItem implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = -904360230041854157L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cartItemId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
@JsonIgnore
private Cart cart;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "productId")
private Product product;


private int quantity;
private double totalPrice;

public int getCartItemId() {
    return cartItemId;
}

public void setCartItemId(int cartItemId) {
    this.cartItemId = cartItemId;
}

public Cart getCart() {
    return cart;
}

public void setCart(Cart cart) {
    this.cart = cart;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public double getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}

public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}
}
```

Here's the dao or "data accessing object":

```
package com.emusicstore.dao.impl;


import com.emusicstore.dao.CartItemDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Cart;
import com.emusicstore.model.CartItem;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dwight on 4/18/2016.
 */

@Repository
@Transactional
public class CartItemDaoImpl implements CartItemDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addCartItem(CartItem cartItem){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(cartItem);
        session.flush();
    }

    public void removeCartItem(CartItem cartItem){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(cartItem);
        session.flush();


    }

    public void removeAllCartItems(Cart cart){
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();

        for(CartItem item : cartItems){
            removeCartItem(item);

        }
    }

    public CartItem getCartItemByProductId(int productId){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from CartItem where productId = ?");
        query.setInteger(0, productId);
        session.flush();

        return (CartItem)query.uniqueResult();

    }

}
```

and lastly the view:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/header.jsp" %>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Cart</h1>

                    <p>Selected products in your shopping cart</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div ng-controller="cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')">
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="clearCart()"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Clear cart</a>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.cartItems">
                        <td>{{item.product.productName}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" ng-click="removeFromCart(item.product.productId)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>remove</a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Grand Total</th>
                        <th>{{calGrandTotal()}}</th>
                        <th></th>

                    </tr>

                </table>
                <a href="<spring:url value="/product/productlist"/> " class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js"/> "></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/footer.jsp" %>
```

some nasty little pictures [cartItems error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHXpt.png)

If you need more information I'll gladly provide it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you are referencing cart.cartItems:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in cart.cartItems">
```

but in your Controller, it doesn't look like you have any code that is assigning anything you retrieve from the server to $scope.cart.cartItems.

If the $http.get is returning exactly what you need, then assigning data to $scope.cart.cartItems is probably what you are missing.

Comment: Based on what I've given how would I go about it. I don't have a clue.... I checked the code the other night and I even went all out to find someone posted the guys code b on the internet. I'm not asking that you understand my program in entirety but shold I explicitly add calGrandTotal for the  loop to $scope.cart.cartItems.length in some way and if so how